# Notification icon c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Notify Icon Test Application";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "You have just minimized the application." + Environment.NewLine + "Right-click on the icon for more options.";

notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

I'm using this code in a button in order to minimize the form and pop up a notification. The form is minimizing but no notification is shown. Any help?

Comment: I added the winforms tag, as this looks like winforms code, but If I'm wrong, please edit the tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a Balloon notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373060/show-a-balloon-notification)

Answer (score 3):

You need to give that `NotifyIcon` an `Icon`. You only set the icon for the tooltip.

[This msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/7k989cfy(v=vs.90)) explains how you can add icons to your project's resources. If you create or add an icon named `myIcon` you can use it for your `NotifyIcon` like this:

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = Resources.myIcon;
// and to be sure set it visible
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
```

The static class `Resources` is normally created in the namespace `<yourprojectnamespace>.Properties`.

Comment: what should be written  after the "=" ? what should be my icon?moreover what do we mean by icon?

Comment: @AliJaber updated my answer with a msdn link, hope that helps.

Comment: it had worked using "notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;" thank you again @René Vogt

Comment: @AliJaber the link is in my answer labeled "This msdn article". Just click on these words in the answer.