# C# NotifyIcon Show Balloon Parameter Deprecated

Tags: c#, tooltip, balloon-tip

I am trying to show a `BalloonTip` in my application, and am reading the documentation from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx) but the only methods that display the `BalloonTip`, use `timeout` (specifically `ShowBalloonTip(Int32)` and `ShowBalloonTip(Int32, String, String, ToolTipIcon)`), which is a deprecated parameter as of Windows Vista. What is the proper way to display a `BalloonTip` that doesn't contain a deprecated parameter for Windows 7 and above?

Comment: I believe `BalloonTips` were replaced by [`ToastNotifications`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification).

Comment: @MrAwesome8 So is Windows 7 stuck in the state of not having `ToastNotifications` but having deprecated `BalloonTips`?

Comment: I'm not sure for Windows 7. I've only used `ToastNotifications` with Windows 10.

Comment: `ToastNotification` were introduced in Windows 8, so I'm not sure where Windows 7 falls, thanks for the input though